# Get img currentSrc using Vue

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Basically, I have an img element that looks like this:

```
<img
     ref="primaryImg"
     id="primary-img"
     class="profile-img"
     sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 80vw,
     (max-width: 1440px) 70vw,
     (max-width: 1280px) 60vw,
     (max-width: 1020px) 50vw,
     (max-width: 900px) 40vw,
     (max-width: 800px) 30vw,
     (max-width: 600px) 20vw,
     (max-width: 400px) 10vw,
     80vw"
     :srcset="profile.photos.primary._srcset"
     alt="">
```

`srcset` contains different urls to be used depending on the user's device viewport.

In order to access the element's properties, I used Vue's `this.$refs`.

On `mounted()`, I tried to `console.dir(this.$refs.primaryImg)`.

```
mounted() {
    console.dir(this.$refs.primaryImg);
},
```

It did show the `currentSrc` on the browser's console

[image]

However, when I tried to do this

`console.dir(this.$refs.primaryImg.currentSrc);`

It returns an empty string. I assume this has to be a lifecycle issue, the img src might not be initialized at this point of time. How do I get the `currentSrc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `img` element object is not completely loaded yet when you are trying to log the `currentSrc` property.

So use the `onload` event which is triggered after the `img` element finishes loading:

```
var myImg = this.$refs.primaryImg;
myImg.onload = function(){
    console.dir(myImg.currentSrc);
}
```

Comment: I hereby declare you sir as the Vue/Javascript god of Stackoverflow. Thank you! This solution worked .

Comment: Thank you but there are far many people way better than me :)

Comment: @VamsiKrishna nice answer. I was just wondering where to find this event. I was looking it up here : https://vuejs.org/v2/api/ and couldn't locate it. Any reference would be immensely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @82Tuskers it's not an event particular to vuejs..its the event fired when  a resource is loaded implemented by vanilla javascript... See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Answer (score 2):

Vamsi's answer is correct on the img not being loaded yet. 
To make your currentSrc dynamic, I suggest you capture changes in screensize and update accordingly

First, add `currentSrc` to your data.

```
data () {
  return {
    currentSrc: ''
  }
},
```

Then update it on first img load

```
<img
     ref="primaryImg"
     id="primary-img"
     class="profile-img"
     sizes="(max-width: 1920px) 80vw,
     (max-width: 1440px) 70vw,
     (max-width: 1280px) 60vw,
     (max-width: 1020px) 50vw,
     (max-width: 900px) 40vw,
     (max-width: 800px) 30vw,
     (max-width: 600px) 20vw,
     (max-width: 400px) 10vw,
     80vw"
     :srcset="profile.photos.primary._srcset"
     alt=""
     @load="e => currentSrc = e.target.currentSrc"
     >
```

And to capture changes on screen size change

```
mounted () {
  this.$nextTick(function() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateCurrentSrc);      
  })
},
methods: {
  updateCurrentSrc () {
    this.currentSrc = this.$refs.primaryImg.currentSrc
  }
}
```

And to use `currentSrc`

```
<img :src="currentSrc" v-if="currentSrc">
```

Comment: thanks @jazel! haven't thought about this issue yet. This would definitely help for our website's responsiveness. Thank alot!